# Why my form in ReacJs return empty Json object when I click on submit button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, submit, redux-form

I am trying to send a value as `defaultValue` from my input box to another component using a form in ReactJs. This is my form:

```
    let NameTab = props => {

            const {handleSubmit, reset} = props;
            return (
                <form  className="form" onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
                    <div className="jumbotron">
                <div>
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <div style={{marginTop: -28, marginLeft: -50}}>
                                <input
                                    style={{marginLeft: 170, width: 350, marginTop: 3, height:30}}
                                    className="control-label"
                                    name="name"
                                    type="text"
                                    defaultValue="Michael"
                                    />
                            </div>
                        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-info"
               style={{marginLeft: -60, marginRight: 20, marginTop: 5}}> Submit </button>
        <button className="btn btn-warning" style={{marginLeft: 100, marginTop: 5}}
                onClick={reset}> Reset </button>
             </div>
            </form>
            );
        };
```

The problem is I am getting an empty `Json-object`: `you submitted: {}`
Can anyone help me find why the return object is `null`. I am expecting `{"name":"Michael"}`. Thanks

`Edit`

My handleSubmit method:

```
const showValues = values =>
    new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {  // simulate server latency
            window.alert(`You submitted:\n\n${JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}`);
            resolve();
        }, 200);
    });
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your `handleSubmit` function?

Comment: By any chance are you using redux-form

Comment: `@Shubham Khatri` yes. I am using redux-form.

Comment: `@kqcef` I added `handleSubmit` function.

Comment: You are missing a closing div before the closing form tag

Comment: `@Shubham Khatri`I forgot it when I copied the code, but I am not missing it with me.

Comment: `@Shubham Khatri` I have the same form in another component using `Filed` instead. It works fine. But here I am using `input` because I want to set a `default value` and change it if I want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to set InitialValues to redux form instead of a default, try

```
let NameTab = props => {

            const {handleSubmit, reset} = props;
            return (
                <form  className="form" onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
                    <div className="jumbotron">
                <div>
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <div style={{marginTop: -28, marginLeft: -50}}>
                                <Field
                                    className="control-label"
                                    name="name"
                                    component="input"
                                    type="text"

                                    />
                            </div>
                        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-info"
               style={{marginLeft: -60, marginRight: 20, marginTop: 5}}> Submit </button>
        <button className="btn btn-warning" style={{marginLeft: 100, marginTop: 5}}
                onClick={reset}> Reset </button>
             </div>
            </form>
            );
        };



const mapInitialValues = () => ({
  initialValues: {
    name: "Michael"
  }
});


export default reduxForm({
    form: 'NameTab'
}, mapInitialValues)(NameTab);
```

Comment: `@Shubham Khatri` It is not working. I tried both keeping `defaultValue` and not. and: export default reduxForm({ form:'NamtTab'}, mapInitialValues)(NameTabComponent); - Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be NameTab rather than NameTabComponent

Comment: it is `NameTab` as `let`, but I am calling the file: `NameTabComponent.js`

Comment: `name: "Michael"` - `name` here is this one "Michael" or this `name=`?

Comment: You don't call the fileName, but the compoennt, so should be NameTab only, since the name of your input field is `name` we specify the initialValue as name: "Michael"

Comment: No way. It's not working! i am getting empty input boxes and when i tape something I still getting empty json object...

Comment: I see that you did not make use of Field, can you try the updated code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144941/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-carl).

Comment: When i changed to `Field` the whole `Form` disappear!